# Changing link destination with the pagebeforechange event and keeping it out of the history?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a PhoneGap application that uses jQuery Mobile (jQM). This application has areas that will require the user to be authenticated. So I'm using jQM's `pagebeforechange` to determine if the user needs to authenticate before viewing the page they have requested. If so, I send them to a login page.

I want to keep the login page out of jQM's history tracking. That is, if the user is presented with the login page, but decides to press "cancel," I want the application to go back to the previous page and **not** have a "next" page in the history; the "previous page" would be at the top of the history stack.

Here's how I am handling the login page redirection:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
  if (typeof data.toPage !== 'string') {
    return;
  }

  if (data.toPage.match(/someRestrictedPage/)) {
    data.options.transition = "pop";
    data.options.changeHash = false;
    data.toPage = "myLogin.html";
  }
});
```

For the cancel button of my login page I am doing:

```
$loginCancelButton.bind('click', function() {
  var prevPage = $.mobile.urlHistory.getPrev();

  if (typeof prevPage !== 'undefined') {
    $.mobile.changePage(prevPage.url, {
      changeHash: false,
      reverse: true,
      transition: "pop"
    });
  }
});
```

However, when I do this, I end up with a `$.mobile.urlHistory.stack` with three elements:

```
[ {"index"}, {"login"}, {"index"} ]
```

How do I manage intercepting page changes to redirect to a login form when necessary, but not create an "invalid" navigation history?

Comment: I'd be interested in that as well.

Comment: @tommyd don't get your hopes up. This question gets zero love.

Comment: sitting on almost the same issue

Comment: I've sort of come to the conclusion that I don't need to worry about it since this will be wrapped in a "native" application. That is, the user won't have a back button that I don't control. But it still would be nice to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: the problem will also be that you may be able to pop() off an entry from JQM's history, but then you would have to re-align with the browser history as well.

Answer (score 1):

looking at [the jquery docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html) it mentions that pagebeforeload event needs to be stopped. and then call the data.deferred (resolve or reject).

try changing it to:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    if (typeof data.toPage !== 'string') {
        return;
    }

    if (data.toPage.match(/someRestrictedPage/)) {
        e.preventDefault()
        data.options.transition = "pop";
        data.options.changeHash = false;
        data.toPage = "myLogin.html";
    }
    data.deferred.resolve(/* url */, data.options)
});
```

Comment: From the documentation: "Callbacks bound to this event can call preventDefault() on the event to indicate that they are handling the load request." I am not handling the page load request. I am merely altering which page is going to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the initial problem could be something like:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
if (typeof data.toPage !== 'string') {
    return;
}

if (data.toPage.match(/ your regex /gi))
{
    if (!check_login())
    {
         e.preventDefault();
         data.options.transition = "pop";
         data.options.changeHash = false;
         data.toPage = "#SignIn";
         $.mobile.changePage("#SignIn");
    }
    //data.deferred.resolve('#SignIn', data.options);
 }
});
```

That worked for me just fine.

Comment: And just what is your solution? How about actually explaining what you did?

Answer (score 0):

VeXii's solution seemed to work for me. By simply removing

```
data.deferred.resolve('#SignIn', data.options);
```

and

```
e.preventDefault();
```

On jquery mobile 1.3...

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    if (typeof data.toPage !== 'string') {
        return;
    }

    if (data.toPage.match(/index/)) {
        data.options.transition = "pop";
        data.options.changeHash = false;
        data.toPage = "#login";
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this. The question is two years old and I'm no longer working on the project that generated it. So I can't verify that it solves the problem I was having. Thus, I don't know if I should accept it as an answer. If I could make the question a community wiki, I would.